# Problem with apache rewrite for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, apache, url-rewriting

I struggle with this case for couple hours and cannot figure it out.
Apache is working as proxy reverse for nodejs application working on localhost address - in my case 127.0.0.1:7777 (to be more precise application is adminMongo).
Because I have working apache configuration I don't want to mess with it and reconfigure everything to VirtualHosts so I created Location like this

```
<Location /adminMongo>
        Header edit Location "/app" "/adminMongo/app"

        ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:7777"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:7777"
</Location>
```

Header rewrite I added because application is redirecting (to /app) instantly after I enter on /adminMongo url - now the page is loading but without any js/css files - for each one I get 404
I tried many different RewriteRules but cannot figure it out.
Right now I get e.g. http://x.x.x.x/css/style.css - and it should be http://x.x.x.x/adminMongo/css/style.css (what works correctly if I paste this url in browser).
Sorry - I'm totally lame in apache config ;)

Any ideas ?

**SOLVED**
Finally solved it - the main problem was that request for static files was related to / - just like mottek pointed. Thankfully, adminMongo has option for context so after I added context "adminMongo" all requests should be passed like this 127.0.0.1:7777/adminMongo
Now rewrite can be used and my Location directive looks like this:

```
<Location>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule "/adminMongo/$" "/adminMongo/app/connection_list" [L]
        RewriteRule "/adminMongo/(.*)$" "http://127.0.0.1:7777/adminMongo/$1" [L,P]
</Location>
```

maybe it is not the best solution but at least it's working ;)

Answer (score 0):

The references to your stylesheets/javascript files are defined in your app as `http://x.x.x.x/css/style.css` which i assume works fine when you are not using the reverse proxy. So querying files can be done relative to `/`

By using the reverse proxy in the way you configured it, files must be queried relative to `/adminMongo/`, which matches your observation that using the URL `http://x.x.x.x/adminMongo/css/style.css` works fine.

I can think of following solutions:

1. Adjust apache config, define dedicated virtual host, then configure
   reverse proxy for the new virtual host so you don't need the
   `adminMongo` part to be included in URL.
2. Adjust paths within your app to load resources (css, javascript,
   ...) from `/adminMongo/...`
3. Copy resources of your app to the directory where apache is serving
   files relative to URL `/` from, e.g. to `/var/www/html/css`. This
   will result in apache delivering css, javascript and other static
   content directly

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding virtual host - currently I have working web on /var/www/html and adminMongo is subdir in html dir - without additional hostname I won't be able to create virtualhost only for adminMongo subdir - 2nd point require source code modification so it's not the best solution - 3rd in the worst case it should works but this will create a little mess in html dir. That's why I thought about rewrite - unfortunately - without success so far.